# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{floor( x\cdot 10^n)}{10^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, integers

I want to solve:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{floor( x\cdot 10^n)}{10^n}$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.
Wolfram say to me that the limit is $x$, but I can't understand...
I have thought it is possible to write:
$$\frac{floor( x\cdot 10^n)}{10^n}=floor( \frac{x\cdot 10^n}{10^n})=floor(x)$$
but this does not help me, since the limit would be $floor(x)\neq x$. Can you help me?

Comment: You certainly cannot do as you suggest! If you try it with any numbers, it would imply that 7/10 = floor(7)/10 = floor(7/10) = 0

Comment: oh yes I agree! Thanks for the counterexample!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $x$. The sequence  can be squeezed between $a_n=\frac{x10^n}{10^n}=x$ above and $b_n=\frac {x10^n-1}{10^n}$ below. Both limits are equal to $x$.

Comment: Thank you now it is all clear!